# UnitySocketIO-WebSocketSharp hangs on a handshake loop using Unity webplayer

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I'm using [UnitySocketIO-WebSocketSharp](https://github.com/kaistseo/UnitySocketIO-WebSocketSharp) to connect with a node.js server. If I run the app on Unity in standalone mode, everything goes well; the handshake happens normally and the websocket runs smoothly.
But, if I run in webplayer mode the socket just gives me an eternal handshake loop.

The code I'm using on Unity is exactly [the one from the example](https://github.com/kaistseo/UnitySocketIO-WebSocketSharp/blob/master/Example/CMain.cs).
On the server i'm using a [crossdomain.xml](https://gist.github.com/jorgeguberte/9465786), and [this is what I'm using as the server](https://gist.github.com/jorgeguberte/9465801)

Here's the output from the server. The blue arrow indicates the moment I play the Unity scene:

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for your peoblem?

Comment: I use this fork of websockets sharp. I have tested it on webplayer, android,  and ios with success. I have not tested it with node.js. https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp